# Do divisors of primes plus or minus 2 yield a random walk?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, random-walk

Look at the number of divisors for $n=p \pm 2$, a prime $p$ plus or minus $2$: $\tau(p+2)$ and $\tau(p-2)$.
Define a function $\Delta(k)$ to be $\{+1,0,-1\}$ if,
for $p$ the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ prime, $\tau(p+2)$ is $\{>,=,<\}$ $\tau(p-2)$
respectively.

For example, the $k=10^{\mathrm{th}}$ prime is $p=29$, and $p+2=31$ has $2$ divisors
while $p-2=27$ has $4$ divisors $\{1,3,9,27\}$.
So $\Delta(10) = -1$.

Accumulate $\Delta(k)$, executing what appears to be one-dimensional
random walk:

---

[image: Prime2]

          

<sup>$\max = 113$, $\min = -282$. The $500000^{\mathrm{th}}$ prime is $7368787$.</sup>

---

My question is:

> Does this $\Delta(k)$ quantity return to zero infinitely often,
>   like a random walk revisiting the origin?

Comment: I have a related/followup question here: [Counting divisors of primes plus or minus 2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309134/6094).